# My Mac does not recognize notarized apps any more

Tags: macos, ventura, gatekeeper

I run macOS 13.6 Ventura on two Macs. Last week I couldn't run a printer driver installer on one of them because the installer file was not notarized. I installed the driver anyway with right-click open, because it was the same file I already used for the other Mac some time ago (residing on a shared drive).

But the behavior continued: I cannot install a single app on the problematic Mac regardless where it comes from (outside the App Store). I tried it with known notarized apps which install fine on one Mac, but not on the other.

`spctl` gives different information when run on the two Macs for identical files. Example for problematic Mac:

```
spctl -a -vvv -t install Installer\ for\ OSX.pkg       
Installer for OSX.pkg: rejected
source=Unnotarized Developer ID
origin=Developer ID Installer: OKI ELECTRIC INDUSTRY COMPANY,LIMITED (U38264BY54)
```

Fine Mac:

```
spctl -a -vvv -t install Installer\ for\ OSX.pkg       
Installer for OSX.pkg: accepted
source=Notarized Developer ID
origin=Developer ID Installer: OKI ELECTRIC INDUSTRY COMPANY,LIMITED (U38264BY54)
```

When I download an App from [eclecticlight.co](https://eclecticlight.co/downloads/) (Howard Oakley knows how to notarize apps... ;-) and open it, for example, my fine Mac asks me that it is from the Internet and it has not found any malware, as it should be. My problematic Mac says it cannot search for malware.

One the problematic Mac I also had trouble with corrupted keychains (after the issues with installing began). For example, Xcode couldn't find my signing certificate, the private key was missing and I had to copy the keychain databases from the other Mac because Keychain Access always said my keychain was invalid when I tried to issue a certificate signing request. I do not know if this is related.

I tried `sudo spctl --reset-default` and `sudo cp /var/db/.SystemPolicy-default /var/db/SystemPolicy` in case anything is corrupted, but it did not help.

How can I get my Mac to recognize the perfectly fine, notarized apps?